# insert a new record in existing sqlite3 table in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, sqlite

I am developing an app wherein I obtain the json data from a url and insert the contents in the table. Till here everything works fine but now since the url contents can be changed every time it changes I need to add more stuff to my existing table for a particular person without changing the previous contents. Can you please guide me

The query that I have is as follows :

```
NSString *plquery = @"INSERT OR REPLACE INTO SHOPPERSLIST (COUNT, NAME, DATE, IDNUMBER) VALUES (?, ?, ?,";

      NSString *update = [plquery stringByAppendingFormat:@"%i%@",[accessID integerValue],@")"];
        NSLog(@"%@",update);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert or replace will update existing records if a record with a matching value for the primary key is found.  If you are creating a new record every time, look into using an insert statement only.

Comment: That helped but now I find that since its related to date if I run the app multiple times on a single day the entries get duplicated

Comment: I tried using unique constraint as well but i found that the json data from an url itself contains duplicated entries and I need to filter it. If the same name exists for same date in the json data I want to insert it only once. How can I do this .. Any pointers